# How can i parse the input of a cell into a date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to parse the date entered into a cell, but it looks like it's not working properly

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var date = new Date(e.value);
    sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(date);
}
```

this always prints `01.01.1970`, and also a comparison with another date always fails...
How can I correctly do that?

Comment: In your situation, what is the value of `e.value`?

Comment: for ex. 03.03.2021

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your issue has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date `1/1/1970` happens when you pass `null` into `new Date()`. Thus there is something wrong with the data being passed into it.

I tried recreating your issue and it seems that it happens when the date is just pasted on a cell, not written.

What I have tried is getting the range of the event and getting it's value manually instead of directly getting `e.value`.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange();

  var date = new Date(r.getValue());
  sh.getRange(1,1).setValue(date);
}
```